# Nodejs - So when i attempt to require these classes i can a strange error?

Tags: node.js

I am not sure why i can require these classes without getting an error as seen above.? This is a port of my java project as i am learning nodejs.

I have tried all i know far if anyone is able to help that would be create.

Please view the rest of the code  from my git repo.
https://github.com/sil3nt884/nodejs_play

```
    const Boxtype1= require("./Boxtype1");
    const Boxtype2= require("./Boxtype2");
    const Boxtype3 = require("./Boxtype3")
    const Boxtype4 = require("./Boxtype4");
    const Boxtype5 = require("./Boxtype4");





        module.exports = class Order {
            constructor(cardGrade, height, lenght, width, quantity, colour, colour2, bottom, stabletops, corner, list) {
                this.add =0;
                this.orderList = list;
                this.valid = false;
                this.total =0;
                this.total2= 0;
                this.five = 0.05;
                this.addOrder(cardGrade, height, lenght, width, quantity, colour, colour2, bottom, corner , stabletops);
                this.orderList.addOrder(cardGrade, height, lenght, width, quantity, colour, colour2, bottom, bottom, add, this.valid);
            }
```

This is the Error i am getting

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
                at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
                at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
                at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
                at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
                at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
                at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
                at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
                at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
                at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
                at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ricky\WebstormProjects\untitled\objects\Order.js:3:18)
```

All the boxtype each extend a box parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It said that error occurred in line 3 of `Order.js` file, I checked the file `Boxtype3.js` and found this

```
getCost = function (grade){ }
```

should be changed to

```
getCost(grade){ }
```

p/s: you should also edit `Boxtype4.js` and `Boxtype5.js` also.

Comment: Thank you for help that did the trick.  should have checked my code a bit more carefully.

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)!